# Time Field Management for AM/PM & 24 Hours using PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime-format

I am using two fields in one of my table named as "tbl_TimeTable" in MySQL. Field Names are Start Time and End Time. I need to store Open Time and Close Time using these 2 fields. Now the Problem is Open Time is 09:00:00 AM and End Time is 02:00:00 AM. I can not find my results using this query.

```
Select TIME_FORMAT(a.End_Time, '%r'), a.Company_ID
from tbl_timetable a WHERE
TIME_FORMAT('15:00:00', '%r') BETWEEN
    TIME_FORMAT(Start_Time, '%r') AND TIME_FORMAT(End_Time, '%r')
```

Table contains:

2 as Company_ID and Start_Time = 09:00:00 and End_Time = 02:00:00

Comment: Can you replicate this issue for us on a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: CREATE TABLE TimeTable
 (`id` int, `Start_Time` time, `End_Time` time)
;
 
INSERT INTO TimeTable
 (`id`, `Start_Time`, `End_Time`)
VALUES
 (1, '09:00:00', '02:00:00'),
 (2, '09:00:00', '20:00:00'),
 (3, '09:00:00', '15:00:00')
;

Comment: SELECT
  id
FROM
  TimeTable
 WHERE
 TIME_FORMAT('14:00:00', '%r') 
 BETWEEN TIME_FORMAT('Start_Time', '%r') AND TIME_FORMAT('End_Time', '%r');

Comment: How to run this query with successful result

Comment: ^ Please add those to your question by editing it, and then delete the comments - they are much more readable if well-formatted in the question. And, please create a fiddle!